# Difference between reading a filename from the user using argv and raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

Exercise 15 in Learning Python the Hard Way is about starting to play with the files which are read in the script using two methods:

- through argv, and
- through raw_input.

Here is the script:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
print txt.read()

print "I'll also ask you to type it again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

The author proposes some problems. The fifth one is try to figure out:

```
why one method of getting the filename is better than the other.
```

I would like to know if there is a real advantage in using one rather than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using command line parameters (argv) makes it both possible: interactive **and** noninteractive use. Asking for starting parameters is never clean. Also, when asking, it's pretty much unpractical to get multi-line input.

Argv presents a clean and well-known interface for (simple) structured input.